# how to solve error like partition's table metadata are out of sync for table

Tags: singlestore

Recently i've faced a memsql leaf hardware error and we ended up missing partitions and their data  due to the fact that we run a replication-1 memsql cluster.

Then we started noticing errors like:

"Java.sql.SQLException: Leaf Error (10.XXXX:3306): Partition's table metadata are out of sync for table"

despite having recreated the missing partitions.

Is there a way to approach this issue? Or i will have to drop data in all affected tables and import that from other sources ?

Comment: How did you go about recreating the missing partitions? REBALANCE PARTITIONS FORCE?

Comment: no, could not use any operation on database since partitions that were on the affected hardware were marked as NULL.  So had to create empty partitions on new leafs.  Next step was importing missing data from additional DB that we use but before being able to so that i ended up getting the metadata error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds likely that the imported tables had mismatching table metadata, because the metadata changed at some point in between. You can try:

- Recreate the tables. This can be done by insert-selecting the data into a newly created table (it may not be possible if no select queries work) or reloading the data from an external source.
- Check the table schemas on the recreated partition vs the other partitions and see if you can find the mismatch - you could diff the `show create table`s. Then it may be possible to manually alter on the leaf partitions to correct them, or recreate the formerly missing partition with matching schemas.